# Arbitrary two-way UNIX socket communication

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipc, fork

I've been working on a complex server-client system in C and I'm not sure how to implement the socket communication.

In a nutshell, the system is a server application which communicates with a database and uses a UNIX socket to communicate with one or more child processes created with `fork()`. The purpose of the children is to run game servers. The process of launching a game server is like this:

1. The server/"manager" identifies a game server in the database that is to be made. (Assume database communication is already sorted.)
2. The manager forks a child (the "game controller").
3. The game controller sets up two pipe pairs, then forks, replacing its child's stdin with a pipe, and it's stdout and stderr with another pipe.
4. The game controller's child then runs `execlp()` to begin running the actual game server executable.

My experience with sockets is fairly minimal. I have used `select()` on a server application before to 'multiplex' numerous clients, as demonstrated by the simple example in the GNU C documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html).

I now have a new challenge, as the system must be able to do more: the manager needs to be able to arbitrarily send commands to the game controller children (that it will find by periodically checking the database) and get replies, but *also* expect incoming arbitrary commands/errors from them and send replies back.

So, I need a sort-of "context" system, where sockets are meaningful only between themselves. In other words, when a command is sent from the manager to the game controller, each party needs to be aware of who is asking and know what the reply is (and, therefore, which command it is a reply to).

Because `select()` is only useful for knowing when we have incoming data, and a thread should block on it, would I need another thread that sends data and gets the replies? Will this require each game controller, although technically a 'client', to use a listening socket and use `select()` as well?

I hope I've explained the system and the problem concisely; I will add more detail if required. Thanks!

Comment: I think i understand most of it, but can you explain what you mean by "sockets are meaningful only between themselves"?

Comment: A command sent over a socket will be replied to from its counterpart, like how you `accept()` and you receive an additional socket that flows in the other direction? Or perhaps there is a more efficient way of implementing the underlying extrapolation processes.

Comment: Won't "each party be aware of who is asking" because they know which socket they are recv()'ing the data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am still not really sure I understand exactly where your trouble is, so I will just spout off some things about writing a client/server app.  If I am off track, just let me know.

1. The way that the server will know which clients corresponds to which socket is that the clients will tell the server.  Essentially, you need to have a log-in protocol.  When the game controller connects to the server, it will send a message that says "Hi, i am registering as controller foo1 on host xyz, port abc..." and whatever else the server needs to know about its clients.  The server will keep a data structure that maps sockets to client metadata, state, etc.  Whenever it gets a new message, it can easily map from the incoming host/port to its metadata. Or your protocol can require that on each incoming message, the will client send the name it registered with as a field.
2. Handling the request/response can be done several ways.  First lets deal with the networking part of it on the server side.  One way to manage this, as you mentioned, is by using select (or poll, or epoll) to multiplex the sockets. This is actually usually considered the more complicated way to do things.  Another way is to spawn off a thread (or fork a process, which is less common these days) for each incoming client.  Each spawned thread can read its own assigned socket, responding to messages one at a time without worrying about the fact that there are other clients besides the own it is dealing with.  This simple one to one thread to socket model breaks down if there are many clients, but if that is not the case, then it is worth consideration.

Part 2 really covers only the client sending the server a message, and the server replying.  What happens when the server wants to initiate communication? How does it do it and how does the client handle it? Also, how do you model the model the communication at the application level, meaning assuming we have the read/write part down, how do we know what to send? You will probably want to model things in terms of state machines.  There is also a lot more to deal with like what happens when a client crashes? What about when the server crashes? Also, what if you really have your heart set of using select, perhaps because you expect many client? I will try to add more to this answer tomorrow.